# enable disable swipe gesture swift

Tags: swift, swipe-gesture, ios9.1

My function is the one below
I'm trying to disable text when array reaches its limit.
I'm getting an error of array out of range. What type of condition can I use so that array is disabled when `array1.count` is equal to `swipeCount`.
This is my code:

```
 let array1 = ["a","b","c","d"]

 func getRandom1() {
    for var i = 0; i < array1.count ; i++
    {
        array1.shuffle1()
    }

}

func getText1() {

    self.display.text = "\(array1[i++])"
    swipeCount++
}

func getTextBack() {


    self.display.text = "\(array1[i])"

}


func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

if (sender.direction == .Right)
{

    if swipeCount != array1.count
    {
        getText1()
    }


    else

    {
        getTextBack()
    }

  }


  }
```

Comment: array1 contains all texts like let array1 = ["a","b","c","d"]

Comment: @SabhaySardana: I don't see any code that could cause `array out of range` here. Please show us how `getText1()` and `notText()` are defined.

Comment: `func getText1() {
        
        self.display.text = "\(array1[i++])"
        swipeCount++
    }`
    
    `func noTextBack() {
        
        
        self.display.text = "\(array1[i])"
        
    }`

Comment: Where is `i` defined?

Comment: You're going out of bounds with `array1[i++]`.  Check to make sure there is a next element before incrementing.

Comment: I'm saying the same thing @JAL that i want to apply a condition that when swipeCount  = array1.count noText() works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if swipeCount != array1.count
```

to

```
if swipeCount < array1.count - 1
```

---

I think you cannot use i in the getText1 and getTextBack. Instead of using i, you should use swipeCount like so:

```
func getText1() {
    self.display.text = "\(array1[swipeCount++])"
}

func getTextBack() {
    self.display.text = "\(array1[swipeCount])"
}
```

Comment: I have tried that before , I have just updated my code . you can see that in my edits :)

Answer (score 1):

```
func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

if (sender.direction == .Right) {
   let aCount = array1.count - 1

   if swipeCount < aCount
{
    getText1()
}


else

{
    getTextBack()
}

}
```